# Is it safe to use short bits from manual screwdriwer with electric drill?

Tags: bits, drill-bit

Is it safe to use short bits (from manual screwdriver) with electric drill Ryobi R18PD3?
Length of the hexagonal part (that fits into the drill) is 1.5cm.  Original bits seems to be a bit:) longer.

Once properly set, bit sits firmly into the chuck of the drill- but bit does not reach the bottom of the chuck.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is safe, but you lose the ability to drill/screw into tight places or longer holes.

Comment: In my experience their biggest danger is their small size causes then to get dropped and fall into crevices never to be seen again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's reasonably safe, but there's a small risk that the bit may slip into the chuck at an inconvenient time,

Sockets are available to to hold these short bits improving reach and removing the risk of slippage.

[image]

Sometimes the bits sold with cheap manual screwdrivers are of poor quality (like made of soft steel)

Comment: +1, but I'd definitely spend the extra on one with a locking mechanism, even if it does make them a tad wider - after you've picked the hex bit back out of the screw you were putting in… for the 135th time… you'll thank me. Example https://www.toolstation.com/dewalt-lockable-magnetic-bit-holder/p14196 [personally I use Wiha bits & holders, but they're 5x the price]

Comment: For slotted screws, you'll want a "finder driver" (the kind with a collapsible sheath). @Tetsujin - bits that short usually don't have a lock recess; you just need a nice new driver where it actually sticks. Also, *screw* hex head. I buy every box of combination square-drive I can get my hands on.

Comment: @Mazura - agreed, though I only ever take out slot-heads, I never put them in;) I've gone with Torx-head screws recently. btw, the OP's bits do have the lock recess, half-way down - I've found even the cheap ones people buy you for xmas still have that, though sometimes they don't *quite* seat as easily.

Answer (score 4):

Done this often, but make sure the chuck is tight, otherwise when you push hard the bit can disappear into the chuck and you thump the work - possibly leaving a mark.